# Embedded twitter feed looks too small displayed on iOS7 Safari iPhone

Tags: css, ios7, twitter, safari, xhtml

I'm embedding a twitter feed in a web page. On iOS7 Safari iPhone, it's squeezed into a tiny rectangle.

[image: Got a magnifying glass?]

I've tried transform of every possible element, embedding in div, tables, etc. It never seems to change size.

I know I can ask the user to pinch out to see the text, but I'd prefer it fill the whole page automatically.

Does anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw your page on iPhone, looks great! In your CSS, you can add filtering with `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1` or `-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 2` and remove the -mos-, -ms-, and -o- transformations.

Answer (score -1):

With a bit of searching, some guesswork and advice from Yimin Rong, came up with this CSS which seems to work:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{
    iframe[id^='twitter-widget-']
        {
            -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
            transform-origin: 0 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.85);
            transform: scale(1.85);
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find the answer here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Put these tags in your head section:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1.0">
```